# Wifi and Bluetooth breaking on Surface Pro 3's

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro-3

So, we're starting to hear from several of our Surface Pro 3 users that their WiFi and Bluetooth has stopped working recently. And by recently, I mean over the last 2-3 weeks, tops. We've reimaged them using our corporate SCCM offline image, and no help. The Surface Pro 3 drivers in the image haven't been updated in several months, and other SP3's have been imaged during that time successfully. So it's not that. And the SP3's that have been re-imaged today didn't have enough time to install updates deployed by SCCM, so that's not it. It at least SEEMS to be hardware, but it's damn odd that it's hit 4 devices in the last 2-3 weeks.

As far as drivers, here's the deal. The SP3 uses the Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC NIC, and device manager isn't showing any issues with it. In fact, the only device that's showing any alerts in Device Manager is "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)". I've looked up the device ID, but I can't find any specifics on the device, only that the manufacturer appears to be Microsoft. This may be a false trail that I'm following, but since it's the only thing that appears wrong, who knows. Here's some of the info from the device.

Device Instance Path - USB\VID\0000&PID_0002\5&16B1AE89&0&6

Hardware IDs - USB\DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_FAILURE

Class Guid - 36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000

BIOS device name - _SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06

I'm seeing some other posts about similar issues on SP3's, but I haven't seen anything regarding actual fixes. These were purchased on a corporate account so we can get them replaced, but if it's an easy fix I would rather go that route since not everyone works out of the office. Or even comes to the office frequently.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if any additional info is needed. Also, this isn't the Win10 1709 issue with breaking WiFi connections, since we haven't deployed 1709 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me to solve the issue with the "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)."

1. Control Panel- Programs- Programs and Features- Turn Windows features on or off (left column).
2. Under the windows features window that will pop up, find "Hyper-V." Click on the box to check it and turn it on. Your computer will install it and then restart.
3. Once computer restarts: Control panel- hardware and sound- power options- make sure that power plan is checked on "balanced," if it isn't then select balanced.
4. In that same window click on "choose what the power button does" (left column). Click on "change settings that are currently unavailable." Turn off "turn on fast startup" and leave only "lock" checked in. Save changes and return to power options screen where you select the power plan (control panel-harware and sound- power options).
5. Next to your "balanced" power plan selection is a blue link to "change plan settings." Click and choose "change advanced power settings." Find the "wireless adapter settings" dropdown and make sure that both features under the "power saving mode" are set as Maximum Performance. Click apply and ok.

(IF THIS FEATURE DOES NOT SHOW FOLLOW THESE STEPS FIRST AND THEN REPEAT STEP 5:
1. Press the Windows Button (next to Ctrl) + R
2. Type: regedit then click enter.
3. Allow application to run.
4. Computer- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE- SYSTEM- Current Control Set- Control- Power (click on folder, not dropdown).
5. Find CsEnabled, double click, change "value data" to 0, and click ok.
6. Now you will be able to see the "wireless adapter settings" return to original step 5 and repeat.)

6. Close the Power Option window and return to Programs and Features (Control Panel- Programs- Programs and Features).
7. Turn Windows features on or off (left column)- uncheck "Hyper-V"- Click ok.

You can then return to the device manager and you will see that "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)" no longer has the yellow warning sign. If the sign was not removed you can restart your computer or disable the device and then enable it again.

This solved my issue with the USB Device but it has not resolved the same issue I am experiencing with the wifi, still working around it. If I find a solution I will post it.

Best of luck!

Comment: +1, we just had a similar problem on one of our Surface Pro devices and changing the wireless adapter power savings settings as you suggest resolved it.  (for the record, we didn't need to turn on Hyper-V or turn off Fast Startup.)